# json properties, turn to variables then transfer to the view

Tags: php, laravel

I have a json file with custom data, a list of some game servers. The json file contains the name and other data...

```
{
 "gameServer1": {
    "name": "game server",
    "ip": "game.gameservers.com",
    "port": "25565",
    "about": "About this game server",
    "nav": {
        "navigationLink1": {
            "name": "Forum",
            "link": "gameserver.com/someurl"
        }
    }
  // etc.. There would be quite a few other servers listed...
 }   
}
```

Now, in my HomeController (since this is where the data would be presented) I am pretty lost, all I have is..

```
public function show()
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('home')->with('servers', $this->getServers());
}

public function getServers(){
    $file = file_get_contents(app_path() . '/views/servers.json');
    $servers = json_decode($file);
    return $servers;
}
```

And I am pretty sure that's wrong. I just don't know how to do this correctly. What I need to do is pass the properties to my home view

```
public function show()
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('home')->with($this->getJSON());
}
```

So I can foreach the results and have something like this presented...

```
    <div class="server">
        <h3 class="server-name">{{n $name }}</h3>
        <div class="ip-address">
            {{ $ipaddress }} 
        </div><!-- /.ip-address -->
        <div class="about-server">
            {{ $about }}
        </div><!-- /.about-server -->
        <div class="server-nav">
        <div class="nav-info">
            <strong>Quick Links</strong>
        </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">{{links}}</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
 etc....
</div><!-- /.server-container -->
```

I feel like I'm not even close to figuring out how to do this though. What to do?

Comment: So it's working, but you are wondering if there is a nicer solution, right?

Comment: No, it's not working. How do I get the returned array to the view? So I can use laravel's @foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the data to your view you should give a name in the `with` method so using that given name you'll be able to access the data in your view, for example you have following code now:

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('home')->with($this->getJSON());
```

You need to pass a name (anything) for the variable like this:

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('home')->with('servers', $this->getJSON());
```

Now you can access the data in your view by referring the `$servers` variable. Since your `$servers` variable will contain an array of `stdClass` so you may loop the `$servers` variable in the view like this:

```
<div class="server">
  @foreach($servers as $server)
    <h3 class="server-name">{{ $server->name }}</h3>
    <div class="ip-address">
        {{ $server->ip }} 
    </div>
    <div class="about-server">
        {{ $server->about }}
    </div>
    <div class="server-nav">
    <div class="nav-info">
        <strong>Quick Links</strong>
    </div>
        <ul>
            @foreach($server->nav as $linkObj)
                <li><a href="{{ linkObj->link }}">{{ $linkObj->name }}</a></li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Each `{{ }}` will print out the `$server->properties` from the `stdClass` object. This is an example of `Blade` template and when you call this:

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('home')->with('servers', $this->getJSON());
```

The framework looks for the view in `app/views/home.blade.php` so make sure you have created the `home.blade.php` view file in `app/views` folder. This is just a simple idea but you need to [read the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/templates).

Comment: Thank you! I understand completely now, though one thing. navigationlink1 would just be a random name that's related to the link, how would I foreach $server->nav and still get a set of links without refrencing the name of it, which in this case would be navigationlink1. so foreach $server->nav instead.

Comment: Any reason you think $servers is returning null in the view?

Comment: Instead of returning `$servers` from your function check `dd($servers)` in `getJSON` and make sure it has data.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. I am really grateful for the help. But I updated the post. It's returning NULL.

Comment: Check the function return value, make sure there is a file with that name exists.

Comment: Returning $file outputs the file contents, weird.

Comment: Wow! appreciate it. You can up vote once tho, most welcome :-)